# How do I detect a specific page in a js script so that I can return from the function?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

I don't think my question needs much more context but the basic problem I'm facing is that I have a script running to hide the nav bar, simple stuff. I have a page that has very little content but it's enough to have a small scroll and due to this, the page looks ugly if a user scrolls.

I tried:

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/page.php") {
  return;
} else {
  //code...
}
```

But it's not working for some reason. The `else` block is still running. My URL is something like `localhost/foldername/page.php?data=something`

I'm using xampp and no frameworks as I've just started learning Web Development last week so any solutions that do not include any frameworks is appreciated. I will learn frameworks, just not now

Comment: You'd be better off using CSS to hide the scrollbar on said page with `overflow: none`. Having said that, why not simply only include the JavaScript *on* the page itself? That way you don't have to worry about a conditional at all. And yes, your `if` conditional won't be entered, because that's not what `window.location.pathname` returns. You need to also reference the folder.

Comment: Obsidian Age It's a common file I use for all pages so I don't have to repeat code. Also, although it can be fixed by not including the file, if in the future I had a file in which I wanted some code not to run, I wouldn't know what to do. I'm learning so I want to take the inefficient path but the path with the better learning curve if that makes sense. Thanks for you response though. I appreciate it

Comment: Your else is always triggered because your expression is flawed. It should be `window.location.pathname == “/foldername/page.php”`

Comment: `/foldername/page.php` !== `/page.php` - it's a simple equality check you've done wrong

Comment: Did you try `console.log(window.location.pathname)` to see if it was actually the value you were expecting? That's the first step in debugging something like this.

Comment: Wow... Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the url is `http://localhost/foldername/page.php?data=something` then the pathname will be:

```
/foldername/page.php
```

So try just checking for that filename

```
if(window.location.pathname.includes("/page.php")) {
   //code...

}
```

Or use the full pathname

```
if(window.location.pathname === '/foldername/page.php)...
```